# pyyaml distribution not found

Tags: pyyaml

I already installed pyyaml,why the hint still says:"pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pyyaml "

```
root@AR:/usr/local/gude/gude-dir# gude build
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/gude", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2707, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 686, in         require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pyyaml

root@AR:/usr/local/gude/gude-dir# pip install pyyaml
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyyaml in 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
root@AR:/usr/local/gude/gude-dir#
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `gude build` runs python probably from `/usr/bin/python` based on pyyaml not being found in `/usr/lib/python2.7/....`.
But your pip says `pyyaml` is satisfied in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/....`.

What has probably happened is that you installed a newer python under `/usr/local`. I would try to install `pyyaml` using your package manager (`apt-get`/`yum`) or alternatively using `/usr/bin/pip install pyyaml`.

You should IMO never install python packages with pip, or via such a `gude buidl` in your systems python installation, as it is possible, and not even difficult, to break things. Instead always create a virtualenv (after e.g. installing that with your package manager) for each utility. You can do so from the systems python or a newer version. And then install any packages needed in the virtual environment.

The root for the problem is of course that `gude build` should just take proper care of its dependies.

Comment: yes,@anthon, u are right.after setting up virtualenv,running "gude build" encounters no error.